# Como seleccionar un archivo en Android 13 o superior? Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

Quiero seleccionar un archivo desde el almacenaminento pero cuando hago la solicitud de permisos siempre devuelve Denegado.

Este es el metodo que tengo para la verificacion y solicitud de permisos:

```
private async Task<PermissionStatus> VerificarPermisos()
{
    try
    {
        var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            return status;

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            return status;
        }

        if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.StorageRead>())
        {
        }

        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

        return status;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Y en este metodo trato de abrir el selector de archivos:

```
private async void AbrirSelectorArchivo()
{
    try
    {
        PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await VerificarPermisos();
        if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            fileResult = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
            if (fileResult != null)
            {
                string fileName = fileResult.FileName;
                lblArchivoSeleccionado.Text = fileName;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

En Android 12 para abajo funciona, pero de Android 13 para arriba ya no funciona.